# How to remove nested sub-form from the sub-form itself?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, controlvalueaccessor

I have a parent form that contains a formArray which can I dynamically append additional formGroups to on click of a button that calls `addForm()`:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.signupForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    formList: this.formBuilder.array([this.formListGroupDef()]),
  });
}

formListGroupDef() {
  return this.formBuilder.control(
    {
      firstName: '',
      email: '',
    },
    Validators.required
  );
}

// Triggered on click of a button in the HTML
addForm() {
  this.formList.push(this.formBuilder.control({ firstName: '', email: '' }));
}
```

In the parent form template, I iterate through the formArray and render them using the nested sub-form `app-profile-form` that implements `ControlValueAccessor`

```
<ng-container formArrayName="formList">
  <div *ngFor="let fg of formList.controls; let infoIndex = index">
    <app-profile-form
      [formControlName]="infoIndex"
      [formIndex]="infoIndex"
    ></app-profile-form>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

`app-profile-form` template:

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
  <label for="first-name">First Name</label>
  <input formControlName="firstName" id="first-name" />
  <div *ngIf="firstNameControl.touched && firstNameControl.hasError('required')" class="error">
    First Name is required
  </div>

  <label for="email">Email</label>
  <input formControlName="email" type="email" id="email" />
  <div *ngIf="emailControl.touched && emailControl.hasError('required')" class="error">
    Email is required
  </div>

  <!-- delete the sub-form on click of this button and update the formList array in the parent form --> 
  <button name="deleteForm" (click)="delete()">Delete Form</button>
</div>
```

As the sub-form can be used on different parent forms, I need to be able to delete the sub-form within itself on the click of the `deleteForm` button and update the formList array in the parent form. How can I achieve this?

Here's my [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bzw5ts?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fprofile-form%2Fprofile-form.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fprofile-form%2Fprofile-form.component.ts). I need to implement the `delete()` function in `profile-form.component.ts`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have nice work with `DI` here, which is the power of Angular. So, just inject `NgControl` and get its parent. Here is the solution:

`profile-form.component.ts`

```
...
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private injector: Injector)
...

delete() {
  // get the current NgControl directive here
  const controlName = this.injector.get(NgControl);
  // get the current FormArrayName directive here and get its control
  const formArray = this.injector.get(FormArrayName).control;
  // find the index, if your control exists in the FormArray
  const index = formArray.controls.findIndex((control: AbstractControl) => control === controlName.control);

  // and what you actually need to do
  if (index > -1) {
    formArray.removeAt(index);
  }
}
```

Comment: If you interesting to learn more, or make it works not only with `FormControlName` directive, see in the article on Medium: https://medium.com/p/b7f09a485fba